# How to create a Class with single but repeated property

Tags: c#, .net, properties

How to write a C# class that has repeated property? For example here is how the serialized object of this class should look like.

```
<Vehicle>
  <Name>Forcus</Name>
  <Name>Tomry</Name>
  <Name>Hovic</Name>
  <Name>Nima</Name>
</Vehicle>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have multiple properties with the same name.
But you can have a *collection* property, of type `string[]` or `List<string>` to store multiple values.

As a concrete example:

```
public class Vehicle
{
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public List<Vehicle> Names {get { return names; }}

    private readonly List<Vehicle> names = new List<Vehicle>();
}
```

Comment: Added an example - hope that's ok

Answer (score 3):

just add Name(s) to collection

```
public class Vehicle 
{
   public List<string> Name {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Assuming (from the code) that this is intended for `XmlSerializer`, this will not work

Comment: @marc,...i would appreciate if you tell me reason for not working here.

Comment: firstly, `IEnumerable<string>` is not supported by `XmlSerializer`; secondly the member is public

Comment: The exact error message is `{"Cannot serialize member Vehicle.Name of type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable\`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] because it is an interface."}`

Comment: ah yes, but let me check about IEnumerable here